# Creating a boundary for objects

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am fairly new to objective-c and iOS programming in Xcode, and while making my first app I ran into the problem of creating barriers around the edge of the screen which the object cannot pass through. I tried placing objects at the boundary and using CGRectIntersectsRect, but the collision between the boundary and the main object is not registered. Does anyone know how I would go about in doing this?

this is the code that I have used for the object's movement:

```
const float rate= 0.025;
NSTimer *goLeft;
NSTimer *goRight;

- (IBAction)right {

    goRight=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:rate
                                            target:self
                                          selector:@selector(goRight)
                                          userInfo:nil
                                           repeats:YES];
    if (goRight == nil){
        goRight=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:rate target:self selector:@selector(goRight) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }




}



- (IBAction)left{


    goLeft=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:rate
                                           target:self
                                         selector:@selector(goLeft)
                                         userInfo:nil
                                          repeats:YES];
    if (goLeft == nil){
        goLeft=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:rate target:self selector:@selector(goLeft) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }


}

-(IBAction)stopLeft{
    [goLeft invalidate];
    goLeft=nil;
}


-(IBAction)stopRight{
    [goRight invalidate];
    goRight=nil;
}

-(void)goLeft{
    _userToken.center =CGPointMake(_userToken.center.x -20, _userToken.center.y);
}

-(void)goRight{
    _userToken.center =CGPointMake(_userToken.center.x +20, _userToken.center.y);

}
```

And for collision with object at left border (userToken and friendly are both UIImageView). However when they collide NSLog is not executed.

```
 -(void)checkForCollision{
        if (CGRectIntersectsRect(_userToken.frame, _friendly.frame)){
            NSLog(@"Left Intersect");

        }
    }
```

Comment: Give some more context about what your objects are and how they move. Show the code you have tried so far.

Comment: Code added to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say what `_userToken.frame` and `_friendly.frame` are set to when you test - it's a good idea to log them while testing so you can manually verify.

An alternative approach, if the valid screen area is a rect, is to check the intersection of the token and the valid area and verify that it is equal to the token frame:

```
if (CGRectEqualToRect(CGRectIntersection(_userToken.frame, validFrame), _userToken.frame)) { ...
```

It's important when checking by any method that the frames are in the same coordinate space (that the views have the same superview, or that you convert them to the same common superview) - again, logging will help you to verify this.

Aside:

Trying to recreate the timer if it just failed is unlikely to help. And you should really check for an existing timer and invalidate it before creating a new timer (otherwise you could end up with multiple timers running and no way to stop them).

Comment: The collision part has worked perfectly, but how would I stop multiple timers from running?

Comment: You can only stop timers that you have a reference to, so if you loose that reference you can't stop it.